# Unable to resolve "./prebuilt.rn-f9cd27ba.js" from "node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\rn\index.js"

Tags: node.js, firebase

I was writing my code and I want some module to be installed so I installed all the required module but after that, I am getting this (Unable to resolve "./prebuilt.rn-f9cd27ba.js" from "node_modules@firebase\firestore\dist\rn\index.js") error again and again so I tried to uninstall all the module which I have installed and I also tried to reinstall, run npm install, and much more but this issue is not fixed pls help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running a modern version of Node.js (or whatever version your project is using ([`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) can help with this).

Delete your `node_modules` directory and run `npm install` again.

Comment: I have the same problem I deleted node modules ad did npm install same problem still, how to solve this, it happened after I tried to install ionic!

Comment: @S.N please ask a new question and provide some logs. If you link the question here I'll take a look

Comment: @Codebling I have updated the Error logs, I am also facing same issue

Comment: @Sanjeev this is a different issue. Please open a new question